# SQLite SELECT row WHERE number of fields not equal to null falls within a range

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to group a dataset into manageable chunks. In order to prioritize which records to focus on first, I want to group records into chunks of "completeness" level where completeness == the number of columns not equal to null in a given row. I'm having trouble with the logic to only return rows with a certain number of columns is not equal to null.

For example if I had a table with 10 columns, and 10 rows.

1. Group 1 would contain all rows where the number of columns not equal to null for a given row is greater than or equal to 8. 
   ie.) IS NOT NULL >=8
2. Group 2 would contain all rows where the number of columns not equal to null for a given row is greater than or equal to 6, and less than 8. 
   ie.) IS NOT NULL >=6 AND IS NOT NULL <8
3. Group 3 would contain all rows where the number of columns not equal to null for a given row is greater than or equal to 4, and less than 6.
4. Etc.

My query below is the closest attempt, but it's obviously broken, and I'm not sure how I would loop through each column and have `Logic` increment by 1 each time instead of just replacing the single value with 1 or 0. Would it be best to do it this way? Where I am looping through and incrementing a value in a new column based on the number of NULL columns, and then just filtering based on this value?

Alternatively, I'd ideally be able to simply only return rows where the number of columns not equal to null falls within a given range. But I'm not sure if this is possible in SQLite.

```
SELECT *
CASE WHEN * IS NOT NULL
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END AS Logic
FROM contacts_all
WHERE Logic >=8;
```

Is this possible in SQLite? I've tried to do this in Python is well, but the dataset is so massive that it crashes my computer every time. Frankly, likely because my python code is garbage.

Any feedback or thoughts would be super valuable and appreciated, thank you!

EDIT: It's also worth mentioning that any solution involving typing out the names of each of the columns is not ideal (although appreciated!) as the number of columns is 247. I'd hope to avoid typing out each of those names into a query. Although I could just CONCAT for formatting in Excel, I'd love to learn how to actually do this in SQL.

EDIT2: Here is an example table and desired results:

```
+---------+---------+---------+------+
|  Col1   |  Col2   |  Col3   | Col4 |
+---------+---------+---------+------+
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | NULL |
| Banana  | 123     | NULL    | NULL |
| Banana  | 123     | NULL    | NULL |
| Banana  | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |
+---------+---------+---------+------+
```

Group 1: WHERE number of fields not equal to null >= 3
Returns Row 1

Group 2: WHERE number of fields not equal to null <3 AND >=2
Returns Rows 1, 2, 3

Group 3: WHERE number of fields not equal to null <2 AND >= 1
Returns Rows 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: For this requirement a table with 247 columns is a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your condition like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM contacts_all
WHERE 
  (col1 IS NOT NULL) + (col2 IS NOT NULL) + (col3 IS NOT NULL) + (col4 IS NOT NULL) + (col5 IS NOT NULL) + 
  (col6 IS NOT NULL) + (col7 IS NOT NULL) + (col8 IS NOT NULL) + (col9 IS NOT NULL) + (col10 IS NOT NULL) >= 8
```

Every condition `(colX IS NOT NULL)` evaluates to `1` for `TRUE` or `0` for `FALSE`.
You can use `BETWEEN 6 AND 7` instead of `>= 8` or any other valid operator.
Or use a `CTE` in which you will calculate the number of not null columns:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
    (col1 IS NOT NULL) + (col2 IS NOT NULL) + (col3 IS NOT NULL) + (col4 IS NOT NULL) + (col5 IS NOT NULL) + 
    (col6 IS NOT NULL) + (col7 IS NOT NULL) + (col8 IS NOT NULL) + (col9 IS NOT NULL) + (col10 IS NOT NULL) AS Logic
  FROM contacts_all
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE Logic >= 8
```